# Format conversion of localized file | xliff to csv

Tags: bash, linux

I need a revision for this code... it's a working code, but i'm pretty sure that can be simplified or even improved. This is for converting a normal xliff file (localization file) into a csv, having this content "ID","SOURCE","TARGET" aligned on the same line.

This is an example of the file i'm trying to convert:

```
...
      <trans-unit xml:space="preserve" id="3952276-0-1" approved="yes">
        <source>There is a woman in town by the name of Elsie Dolban. She is eccentric, and that has caused some of the villagers to condemn her. I'm interested in *your* opinion of her.\n\nSpeak to Inquisitor Roche, he has strong opinions in this matter.</source>
        <target state="translated">C'è una donna in città che si chiama Elsie Dolban. E' una donna eccentrica e questo l'ha portata a essere condannata dai cittadini. Vorrei sapere la *tua* opinione su di lei.\n\nParla con l'Inquisitore Roche, la sua opinione ha un certo peso in questa faccenda.(ITALIANO)</target>
      </trans-unit>
      <trans-unit xml:space="preserve" id="3952276-0-2">
        <source>Cursed werewolves! They've been attacking us ever since the Warden sent us west, intent on overrunning our camp. Will you help thin their ranks a bit?</source>
        <target></target>
      </trans-unit>
      <trans-unit xml:space="preserve" id="3952276-0-3">
        <source>Why do I have the best brew in Northmoor? I'll let you in on the secret… it's the hops! The Wolf Moors to the west seem to be the only place they grow and that's too dangerous for the likes of me. If you could bring me some, I'd be in your debt.</source>
        <target></target>
      </trans-unit>
      <trans-unit xml:space="preserve" id="3952276-0-4">
        <source>We're short on weapons here, and it seems to me one's as good as another. I've seen zombies roaming the ruins to the southeast. Go slay a few and take their blades. We'll put them to better use.</source>
        <target></target>
      </trans-unit>
      <trans-unit xml:space="preserve" id="3952276-0-5" approved="yes">
        <source>We need more people keeping an eye on things out in the streets. If you wouldn't mind doing a patrol loop, I'll give you a patroller's day wages.\n\nTalk to Watcher Emeric, just outside. He'll give you the details.</source>
        <target state="translated">Abbiamo bisogno di più persone che sorveglino le strade. Se non ti dispiace fare un turno di pattuglia, ti pagherò il salario giornaliero da sentinella.\n\nIl Guardiano Emeric è qui fuori. Parla con lui, ti fornirà i dettagli.(ITALIANO)</target>
      </trans-unit>
      <trans-unit xml:space="preserve" id="3952276-0-6">
        <source>I'm worried about two of my orators in the city, Simine and Dalomar. The Magis Order has been harassing them, and I'm concerned that might escalate. Can you check on them? Simine is close by, but I don't know where Dalomar is.</source>
        <target></target>
      </trans-unit>
...
```

This is the code i'm using for... basically i use `grep` to select the content between `<source></source>` and `<target*></target>` tags and `sed` for telling the **content** in the **argument of the `<trans-unit` tag**... i hope there are other better solutions :)

```
FILE_XLIFF=$1
FILE_CSV=$2

FILE_ID="ID.txt"
FILE_SOURCE="EN.txt"
FILE_TARGET="IT.txt"

echo "Creating ID file..."
FILE_TEMP1=$(sed -n 's/.*id="\([^"]*\).*/\1/p' "$FILE_XLIFF" > $FILE_ID)
echo "Creating SOURCE file..."
FILE_TEMP2=$(grep -o '<source>.*</source>' "$FILE_XLIFF" | sed 's/\(<source>\|<\/source>\)//g' > $FILE_SOURCE)
echo "Creating TARGET file.."
FILE_TEMP3=$(grep -o '<target.*</target>' "$FILE_XLIFF" | sed -e 's/\(<target>\|<\/target>\)//g' -e 's/\(<target state="translated">\|<\/target>\)//g' > $FILE_TARGET)

echo "Format conversion of following files..."
dos2unix $FILE_ID
dos2unix $FILE_SOURCE
dos2unix $FILE_TARGET

n=$( wc -l < "$FILE_ID" )

exec < $FILE_ID
exec 3< $FILE_SOURCE
exec 4< $FILE_TARGET

echo "Creating CSV file"
for ((i=1; i<=n; ++i)); do
read -r LINE_ID
read -r -u 3 LINE_SOURCE
read -r -u 4 LINE_TARGET
echo "\"$LINE_ID\",\"$LINE_SOURCE\",\"$LINE_TARGET\""
done > $2

exit
```

Each TEMP_FILE, is a list of the collected strings like this

FILE_TEMP1

```
3952276-0-1
3952276-0-2
3952276-0-3
3952276-0-4
3952276-0-5
3952276-0-6
```

FILE_TEMP2

```
There is a woman in town by the name of Elsie Dolban. She is eccentric, and that has caused some of the villagers to condemn her. I'm interested in *your* opinion of her.\n\nSpeak to Inquisitor Roche, he has strong opinions in this matter.
Cursed werewolves! They've been attacking us ever since the Warden sent us west, intent on overrunning our camp. Will you help thin their ranks a bit?
Why do I have the best brew in Northmoor? I'll let you in on the secret… it's the hops! The Wolf Moors to the west seem to be the only place they grow and that's too dangerous for the likes of me. If you could bring me some, I'd be in your debt.
We're short on weapons here, and it seems to me one's as good as another. I've seen zombies roaming the ruins to the southeast. Go slay a few and take their blades. We'll put them to better use.
We need more people keeping an eye on things out in the streets. If you wouldn't mind doing a patrol loop, I'll give you a patroller's day wages.\n\nTalk to Watcher Emeric, just outside. He'll give you the details.
I'm worried about two of my orators in the city, Simine and Dalomar. The Magis Order has been harassing them, and I'm concerned that might escalate. Can you check on them? Simine is close by, but I don't know where Dalomar is.
```

FILE_TEMP3

```
C'è una donna in città che si chiama Elsie Dolban. E' una donna eccentrica e questo l'ha portata a essere condannata dai cittadini. Vorrei sapere la *tua* opinione su di lei.\n\nParla con l'Inquisitore Roche, la sua opinione ha un certo peso in questa faccenda.(ITALIANO)
[nothing]   
[nothing]
[nothing]
Abbiamo bisogno di più persone che sorveglino le strade. Se non ti dispiace fare un turno di pattuglia, ti pagherò il salario giornaliero da sentinella.\n\nIl Guardiano Emeric è qui fuori. Parla con lui, ti fornirà i dettagli.(ITALIANO)
[nothing]
```

***Where is nothing, it's a white line cause the line is not translated in the target tags***...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Pointless variables

These variables are pointless:

> ```
> FILE_TEMP1=$(sed -n 's/.*id="\([^"]*\).*/\1/p' "$FILE_XLIFF" > $FILE_ID)
> FILE_TEMP2=$(grep -o '<source>.*</source>' "$FILE_XLIFF" | sed 's/\(<source>\|<\/source>\)//g' > $FILE_SOURCE)
> FILE_TEMP3=$(grep -o '<target.*</target>' "$FILE_XLIFF" | sed -e 's/\(<target>\|<\/target>\)//g' -e 's/\(<target state="translated">\|<\/target>\)//g' > $FILE_TARGET)
> ```

Since the `$(... > somefile)` subshells all redirect their output to a file, the output is empty, so these variables will contain nothing. They are also not used in the script.

#### Combine `grep -o` and `sed`

The `grep -o` and `sed` commands mentioned in the previous section can be combined:

```
sed -ne 's?.*<source>\(.*\)</source>.*?\1?p' "$FILE_XLIFF" > "$FILE_SOURCE"
sed -ne 's?.*<target[^>]*>\(.*\)</target>.*?\1?p' "$FILE_XLIFF" > "$FILE_TARGET"
```

Some other notes:

- `$FILE_SOURCE` and `$FILE_TARGET` should be double-quoted (like you already did other filenames)
- Notice that I used `?` is the pattern separator in the `sed` expressions so I don't need to escape the embedded `/`

#### Double-quoting paths

Remember to always double-quote variables that contain paths, for example:

```
dos2unix "$FILE_ID"
dos2unix "$FILE_SOURCE"
dos2unix "$FILE_TARGET"
```

#### Simpler CSV transformation

Instead of the for loop over the lines of multiple files,
it will be simpler and faster to use `awk`:

```
paste "$FILE_ID" "$FILE_SOURCE" "$FILE_TARGET" |\
awk -F '\t' '{printf "\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\"\n", $1, $2, $3}'
```

#### Pointless `exit`

The `exit` statement at the end of the script is pointless.

Comment: Thank you janos, do you have any idea why the paste command removes double whitespaces in a string?
I explained a little bit more detailed in my previous question: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/113060/91456

Anyway thank you :)

Comment: You're welcome, but answers in this site are not the appropriate place to debug your issues. I left a comment on your answer and deleted it. I could not reproduce the problem you're referring to. You might want to try Stack Overflow for debugging issues. (Make sure to read their help center before posting.)